Detecting that Thrift Server thread is stuck using application watchdog
I'm using Thrift for RPC in my application.
I have an internal application watchdog that I want to use also for monitoring Thrift Server thread health.
(for example to restart the thrift server in case the handler is stuck, i.e. the connection is alive but the processing is stuck)
I've created the following template class that should be wrapper over my Thrift service processer.
template <class TSvcProcessor, class TIface>
class ThriftSvcTrackedProcessor : public TSvcProcessor {

public:

    ThriftSvcTrackedProcessor(::std::shared_ptr<TIface> iface, uint32_t watchdogClientId)
    : TSvcProcessor(iface)
    , watchdogClientId_(watchdogClientId)
    {}

    bool dispatchCall(apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* in,
                      apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* out,
                      const std::string& fname,
                      int32_t seqid,
                      void* callContext) override
    {
        theWatchDog().StartWatch(watchdogClientId_);
        bool result = TSvcProcessor::dispatchCall(in, out, fname, seqid, callContext);
        theWatchDog().StopWatch(watchdogClientId_);

        return result;
    }

    bool process(apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol> in,
                 apache::thrift::stdcxx::shared_ptr<apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol> out,
                 void* connectionContext) override
    {
        theWatchDog().StartWatch(watchdogClientId_);
        bool result = TSvcProcessor::process(in, out, connectionContext);
        theWatchDog().StopWatch(watchdogClientId_);

        return result;
    }

private:

    uint32_t watchdogClientId_;

};

I'm using it in the following way
ThriftServer::ThriftServer(const std::string &rDeviceType, const int port)
    : pHandler_(apache::thrift::stdcxx::make_shared<LocalHandler>())
    , pProcessor_(
        apache::thrift::stdcxx::make_shared<
          ThriftSvcTrackedProcessor<LocalOrRemoteProcessor, ::thrift::MySvcIf>>(pHandler_, theWatchDog().RegisterClient("MyThriftSvc"))
      )
    , pProtocolFactory_(apache::thrift::stdcxx::make_shared<TBinaryProtocolFactory>())
    , pServer_(new TNonblockingServer(pProcessor_, pProtocolFactory_, apache::thrift::stdcxx::make_shared<TNonblockingServerSocket>(port)))
    , pThread_(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&ThriftServer::ThreadMain, this, rDeviceType, port)))
{
}

And ThreadMain function just runs the Serve() function of pServer_.
Is there better way to do it (except overloading processor function)?
I saw that there are some classes provided by thrift that can be used (for example TProcessorEventHandler), but I didn't found examples of how to use them for this.
